# Change A Database's Table's Name (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, datatable, table-rename

I got a table named tblHello and I wanna rename it to Hello

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on the table and select rename in management studio
You can also use sp_rename:

```
sp_rename 'old_table_name', 'new_table_name'
```

Comment: Or just double click on the name if doing it through the UI.

Comment: @Martin - double clicking sometimes works for me.  Its very shady cause other times it simply expands.  So I like to right click or use sproc sp_rename

Comment: @Jon - See what you mean. Looks like it needs a click pause click rather than a double click actually.

Comment: @Martin - Yep that's why I call that shady :)

Comment: The double click or pause click doesnt work (I know how to rename stuff but there isnt an option here) Your code might work but where do I put it?

Comment: @marc_s - I've been a member for quite some time, so I am aware of this, however I am running Internet Explorer 9 and that is a bug on that specific browser...

Comment: @Or Betzalel - You can run that code in a "new query window" within SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: F2 is the Windows standard for rename. Works in SSMS, Explorer, etc. Guaranteed not to unexpectedly launch anything.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that table renaming is not as simple as just changing the name when you have queries written. You also need to change all references to the old name in every stored proc, view, function and dynamic sql code. This is not something to be taken on lighty in something that is already on production.

But @jonH has the answer for how to do it (you run that in the query window making sure you switch to the correct database first).  Of course you have to have the right security permissions to rename objects.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it, and by the way its a small project so ctrl+H will do the trick

Comment: Awesome! Worked Great. I can't V you since he kinda gave the answer, sorry. gonna have to settle for 1 point

Answer (score 0):

If its a small project,
you can directly change it from User Interface.

In Server Explorer, right-click the table you want to rename and Open `Table Definition`.

Right-click the table in the Table Definition window and choose `Properties` from the shortcut menu.

In the field for the `Name` value in the Properties, type a new name for the table.

Save the table.

And its done.